# How to disable persistent connection between php and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, php-7, php-mongodb

When I use driver [MongoDB\Driver](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) in PHP7, php always creates lots of connections with mongo. And I can't close the connection by myself, because MongoDB\Driver hasn't a close() method.

How to disable persistent connection? Or how to configure it?